# Hibernate Evict in Service Layer Implementation

Tags: hibernate

I'm having a service class

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImplimplements EmployeeService {
....
....
```

Huge employee records has been retrieved via employee Dao and code is iterating one by one employee object and doing various operations..

Atlast i want to evict the employee object as it is an expensive object and memory is getting increased.
}

Could you please help me on how to invoke evict or proper way to remove the object from the memory?

usually when the hibernate session is available i will be calling hibernate.evict(emp);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you can try [StatelessSession](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html) as stateless session does not implement a first-level cache and light weight compared to `session`. Although it has some limitations as specified in the link

Comment: Can you please paste a code snippet or an example or a link for reference?

Comment: Refer to **section 13.3** of [Stateless Session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)

Comment: can we write a method in DaoImpl to evict the object which is in service layer ? example empDao.evict(emp);

Comment: To make sure I get the flow right, You have a service class that class Dao. The dao uses hibernate session to fetch the data. So in this case `EmployeeService` is calling `employeeDao` to get the list of `Employees` which is very huge. And at the end of service method you want to evict all the employees the session first level cache. Is it right? And where does your transaction start & end, is it in the service method itself? Any second level cache you are using?

Comment: controller -> service -> dao

Comment: @Karhiresa And the `EmployeeServiceImpl` I am assuming it is only reading the `employee` entities from the Dao and making no changes to those entities.And at the end of service method you want to evict all the employees the session first level cache. Is that correct understanding?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have a `EmployeeServiceImpl` class that interacts with `EmployeeDao` to get the `List<Employee>` object. Subsequently you iterate over this list and perform the various operations. And the problem is, this is a very huge list and we have concerns around the memory utilization of this function.

With that, assuming you are not making to these employee entities in the list, below is my view.

> Atlast i want to evict the employee object as it is an expensive
>   object and memory is getting increased. }

if the List is really big, you would see `Hibernate Session` consuming more memory than just the memory required to hold `List<Employee>` objects. Main reason being, `Session` has to maintain the state of each `Employee` object in the form of [`EntityEntry`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/spi/EntityEntry.html) object i.e., one such extra object, EntityEntry, for each `Employee` object. This is needed for hibernate automatic dirty check mechanism to work during the flush stage to compare the current state of entity with its original state (that is stored in `EntityEntry`).

Quoting form the above link:

> We need an entry to tell us all about the current state of an object
>   with respect to its persistent state Implementation Warning: Hibernate
>   needs to instantiate a high amount of instances of this class,
>   therefore we need to take care of its impact on memory consumption.

But if the intent is only to read and iterate through the list of employee and not perform and changes to those employee entities, we can use [`StatelessSession`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html) instead of `Session`.

The advantage being as quoted from above link:

> A stateless session does not implement a first-level cache nor
>   interact with any second-level cache, nor does it implement
>   transactional write-behind or automatic dirty checking

With no automatic dirty checking there is no need for Hibernate to create `EntityEntry` being maintained for each entity of `Employee` as it did in the earlier case with `Session`.

Said that, it does have its own set of limitations as mentioned in the [StatelessSession](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html) documentation.

But, so far based on my understanding of the problem and assumptions I have made, I don't see these limitations would pose any issues or prevent from using StatelessSession`instead of`Session`.

Another option that you brought up:

> can we write a method in DaoImpl to evict the object which is in
>   service layer ? example empDao.evict(emp);

Definitely we can have a method like `empDao.evict(emp)` or `empDao.evict(subListEmp)` that we can call from our `EmployeeServiceImpl` class periodically as we complete predefined number of iterations on the `List<Employee>`, say after iterating every 20/50 employees or so.

If you ask me my preference, I would prefer to go with `StatelessSession` approach unless its limitations doesn't allow me to proceed. And if `StatelessSession` is not feasible for the current problem, because of its inherent limitations, only then I would look at exposing some `evict(..)` in dao and calling it periodically.

Comment: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:515)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)

Comment: @Kathiresa Can u add the complete stacktrace to your question? That would help. On a different note, you may want to consider posting the complete stacktrace along with your hibernate configuration file/class as a new question instead of using this one. To me, it looks like some configuration/setup issue and may not directly related to `evict` related discussion we had on this question.

Comment: Can we add entitymanager in the @service class and call the evict? as i don't think we can use stateless session as the session also does the update

Comment: @Kathiresa you can inject the `entitiManager` in the service as pass that in while invoking the dao. But ideally, dao is the right place for injecting `entityManager`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few alternatives you can also consider without having to bother with a `StatelessSession` should there be reasons to continue using a stateful `Session` instead.

**Callback Interface**

Expose a method on your DAO classes that allow you to provide an implementation of a callback interface that is designed to accept each entity in your list, one by one.

```
public interface EntityCallback<T> {
  boolean doWithEntity(T entity);
}
```

The idea here is that your service layer could invoke a DAO method with the above interface implementation as follows:

```
public <T> void findAll(EntityCallback<T> callback) {
  ScrollableResults<T> results = /* get result set*/

  int iterations = 0;
  while(results.hasNext()) {
    iterations++;
    T entity = results.next();
    if(!callback.doWithEntity(entity)) {
      break;
    }
    if(iterations % 100 == 0) {
      session.clear();
      iterations = 0;
    }        
  }
  results.close();
}
```

The beauty of the above approach is that it prevents leaking any hibernate-specific persistence constructs to the service tier without actually pushing business logic into the data access layer.

**Wrap ScrollableResults Autoclosable Resources**

There could be times where it may be just as simple to iterate the results in the service tier inside the transaction.  By creating a wrapper around the *ScrollableResults* class, you can utilize try-with-resources.

```
public class QueryResult<T> implements Iterator<T>, AutoCloseable {
  /* add implementation stuffs */
}
```

Then inside the service-tier, you can use it as follows:

```
try( Iterator<Entity> it = dao.iterator(...) ) { 
  while( it.hasNext() ) {
    Entity entity = it.next();
  }
}
```

Much like how the `findAll(EntityCallback<T>)` method kept track of the number of iterations, your `QueryResult` class could do the same based on each call to `next()` and thus could automatically clear the session at specific intervals.

The benefit to the try-with-resources approach is that because it uses JDK7's `AutoCloseable` interface, the service tier can simply use it as an iterator without having to be concerned with the underlying result set and closing it.